Find conditional duplicates using SQLite
I have the following table
CREATE TABLE "matches" (
    "match_id"  INTEGER,
    "uts"   INTEGER,
    "player_id" INTEGER,
    "opponent_id"   INTEGER
);

I want to obtain for each match the number of matches the player and opponent have played against each other before that specific match.
uts represents a timestamp and can be used to filter the data.S.
Let's assume I have the following data
39943359    1678449600   1    2 
39943361    1678449600   3    4   
39943363    1678451400   5    6     
39943365    1678451400   5    6  
39943367    1678453200   5    6
39943369    1678453200   1    3
39943371    1678455000   1    2  
39943373    1678455000   1    5

I would expect the following result:
39943359    0
39943361    0   
39943363    0     
39943365    1  
39943367    2
39943369    0
39943371    1  
39943373    0

How to include the uts-condition in
SELECT match_id, COUNT(*)
FROM matches
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(rowid) 
  FROM matches 
  GROUP BY player_id, opponent_id
)


What does it mean that the timestamp for 39943363 is the same as the one for 39943365?

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() window function, which assigns a unique sequential integer to each row, and then calculating a running total to generate the desired output :
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by player_id, opponent_id order by uts) as rn
  from matches
)
select match_id, uts, player_id, opponent_id, sum(1) over (partition by player_id, opponent_id order by rn) - 1 as cnt
from cte
order by match_id

Demo here

I was able to achieve the expected output with
WITH tuples AS (
    SELECT m.match_id AS id, older.match_id AS older
    FROM matches AS m LEFT JOIN matches AS older
        ON m.player_id = older.player_id
        AND m.opponent_id = older.opponent_id
        AND m.uts >= older.uts
        AND m.match_id >= older.match_id
) SELECT id, COUNT(*)-1
FROM tuples
GROUP BY id;

I'm not sure how to interpret the uts being the same for 39943363 and 39943365, though. If the two matches happened at the same time, which one should be considered happening before the other one? (I solved it using the comparison on match_id, but I'm not sure it's what you want.)
